# Accessing Images from gallery and showing in iOS app gallery

Tags: ios, gallery

I have around 1000 ’s  of Images, I want show them in my app. What are the possibilities to do that..

The ideas which I’m thinking

1.Saving all images in phone gallery. accessing images form gallery… but It seems not possible as each iOS app has its own sandbox.

2.Saving in my bundle which will increase the memory size.

In android there is a control called “ViewPager”, how can i achieve the same control in iOS ….

Tried scrollview with paging technique but crashes due to memory ....

Please guide me…..

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can show images from the gallery directly to your application . But you can store it into document directly , for that you have to first pick images from the gallery . you can refer

[How to load photos from photo gallery and store it into application project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605845/how-to-load-photos-from-photo-gallery-and-store-it-into-application-project)

And next time when you start application you can load images from the document directory so you dont need to go to the gallery again .

Comment: If there are 500 images in gallery, is it not good way for selecting each image.. is there any direct way of keeping gallery folder in documents folder...

Comment: No , I dont think so , because you never going to know the path of those images in the gallery